# zeppelin dynamically load jars

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies, apache-zeppelin, livy

Inside Zeppelin I want to be able to dynamically load the jars to Livy from a corporate repository.

```
livy.spark.jars.packages
```

only applies to the interpreter configuration which is restricted due to security constraints.

How can I once setup the allowed repositories in zeppelin and then pull the jars dynamically for Livy similar to what:

```
%spark.dep
z.reset() // clean up previously added artifact and repository

// add maven repository
z.addRepo("RepoName").url("RepoURL")

// add artifact from maven repository, with no dependency
z.load("groupId:artifactId:version")
```

provides

Answer (score 0):

You can try the inline generic interpreter which is introduced in 0.8.0. See https://medium.com/@zjffdu/zeppelin-0-8-0-new-features-ea53e8810235

```
%livy.conf

livy.spark.jars.packages  <your_package>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we only have `0.7.3`. Is there a solution for the old version as well?